# load RAM disk with command

Tags: linux, centos7

How to mount below fstab line with command?in case of I can't restart the server.

```
none                    /var/tmpfs              tmpfs   defaults,size=16g        1 2
```

Comment: Actually off-topic but whatever: `mount -t tmpfs -o size=16g none /var/tmpfs`. BTW, are you sure about the `/var/tmpfs` instead of just `/var/tmp`. But then, if you are modifying `/etc/fstab`, issuing `mount -a` should also do the trick.

Comment: @rodrigo it works,thanks a lot

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up your editor and edit the `/etc/fstab` file

This seems to be your line to mount the partition

```
none /var/tmpfs tmpfs defaults,size=16g 1 2
```

You would normally have to reboot your Linux system, after editing this file.

There is a simple way which will remount all the partitions from your `/etc/fstab` file without restarting the system.

Run the following command as root

```
sudo mount -a
```

After you've done that, do a

```
df -lh
```

you should see your drives listed.